fastapi jsonable_encoder error when returning sqlalchemy db query results
My fastapi component was working well when I was using Python3.8.  Recently, I started upgrading to Python3.12.4 and ended up having issues with fastapi.   The fastapi(0.112.2) jsonable_encoder errors while handling sqlalchemy db query results.  But when I was using fastapi(0.100.0), it was working as expected.  The error now goes like this -
> "..../encoders.py", line 324, in jsonable_encoder
data = dict(obj)
>      ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

I am facing this issue particularly when returning DB query results that contain rows of records formed with a subset or join of columns rather than whole records.
I found some good threads on this  here and  here but I wonder why this fastapi upgrade is forcing a workaround when it was all working well in the older version.
What should be the right approach to solve this ?
